# Site name is nearly unreadable

Tags: feature-request, chat, design

For private betas, the site name is used in the chat and looks like this:

[image]

From the actual size, the text is barely readable. Blue on dark blue doesn't make the text look visible, never mind stand out from the background. The color choice is horrible and the small text makes things even worse. Can we please make the site name more visible in chat (for private betas)?

Comment: This bug exists for years (probably since the very beginning) and applies to all beta sites, not just private.